# VB.NET Compiler : got stuck with "replace"

Tags: vb.net

My code is below : (It was quite long)

```
Module Module1

    Sub EndFunction(Optional ByVal NL As Integer = 0)
        If NL = 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine()
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub HandleCompile(ByVal FileLine As String())

        Dim CurrentLine As String
        Dim CurrentPara() As String
        Dim CurrentUserReadLine As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To FileLine.Length - 1

            CurrentLine = FileLine(i)
            CurrentPara = CurrentLine.Split(" ")

            Select Case CurrentPara(0)
                Case "write"
                    For Count As Integer = 1 To CurrentPara.Length - 1
                        If (CurrentPara(Count).Contains("$readvalue")) Then
                            CurrentPara(Count).Replace("$readvalue", CurrentUserReadLine)
                        End If
                        Console.Write(CurrentPara(Count) + " ")
                    Next
                    EndFunction(1)
                Case "read"
                    CurrentUserReadLine = Console.ReadLine()
                    EndFunction()
                Case "clean"
                    Console.Clear()
                Case Else
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR : NO SUCH FUNCTION")
                    EndFunction()
            End Select

        Next

    End Sub

    Sub Main()

        Dim UserInput As String
        Dim Para() As String
        Dim UserReadLine As String = ""
        Dim FullFile As String
        Dim FileLine() As String

GetInput:
        UserInput = Console.ReadLine()
        Para = UserInput.Split(" ")
        Para(0) = Para(0).ToLower

        For i As Integer = 1 To Para.Length - 1
            If (Para(i).ToLower.Contains("$readvalue")) Then
                Para(i) = Para(i).Replace("$readvalue", UserReadLine)
            End If
        Next

        Select Case Para(0)
            Case "write"
                For Count As Integer = 1 To Para.Length - 1
                    Console.Write(Para(Count) + " ")
                Next
                EndFunction(1)
            Case "read"
                UserReadLine = Console.ReadLine()
                EndFunction()
            Case "clean"
                Console.Clear()
            Case "compile"
                If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Para(1)) Then
                    FullFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Para(1))
                    FileLine = FullFile.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                    HandleCompile(FileLine)
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Cannot Find File : " + Para(1))
                End If
                EndFunction()
            Case Else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR : NO SUCH FUNCTION")
                EndFunction()
        End Select

        GoTo GetInput

    End Sub

End Module
```

In `HandleCompile(FileLine)`, I wish to get every parameter's `$readvalue` to be replaced to `CurrentUserReadLine`. Which means if I wrote such a code in file `C:\easy.txt` :

```
read
write $readvalue
```

And I ran this in the compiler :

```
compile C:\easy.txt
```

What I have expected is :

1. The compiler reads the user's input;
2. It prints out $readvalue, which is the same as the user's input.

However when I try the code above what I get is :

(Line 1 is User Input)

```
abc
$readvalue
```

But I want to see

```
abc
abc
```

I had no idea what's going on. Any answer or comment would be appreciated.

Comment: Standard mistake, String.Replace() is a *Function*.  It cannot update the string object itself, strings are immutable.  It returns a new string.  You are not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to save the result of your replace back into `CurrentPara(Count)`.

```
CurrentPara(Count) = CurrentPara(Count).Replace("$readvalue", CurrentUserReadLine)
```